# How to set maximum height to Monaco Editor?

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, monaco-editor

I am using React Monaco Editor ( https://github.com/react-monaco-editor/react-monaco-editor ). When I set a hardcoded height, I usually see some space on the page. I want to fill that space with Monaco Editor. Page size can be changed so I want the Editor to be dynamic to the page size. This example ( https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html ) is very good. Whenever I change the size of the page, Editor size also changes. Is there a way to do the same thing?

My codes:

```
return (
    <Editor
      options={{ readOnly: !canEditEditor }}
      defaultLanguage="json"
      defaultValue={formatJSON(JSON.stringify(documentInfo))}
      onChange={(value, event) => handleChange(value, event)}
      onValidate={handleValidation}
      className={styles['Editor-container']}
    />
  );
```

---

Scss

```
.Editor-container {
  border: 1px solid var(--ltc-grey200);
  border-radius: 2px;
  margin-top: calc(var(--unit) - 0.5rem);
  height: 60vh;
}
```